# Error 'Not well-formed' using jqgrid

Tags: php, xml, firefox, jqgrid

I am using `jqgrid` in my application, due to recent changes, I was forced to change version of `jqgrid` to `4.4.3` (from `3.3.1`) and then this error started to occur, when `XML` is returned from my webservice, in Console browser I get error saying `Not well-formed`, but everything is working as expected (I get this error on every place where I use `jqgrid`). Also to notice, this error is appearing only in **`Mozilla Firefox`**.

Here is screenshot:
[image]

p.s. I am sure that **`XML`** is well formed.

Anyone else have the same problem? Any suggestion would help.

Simple XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rows>
   <page>1</page>
   <total>1</total>
   <records>1</records>
   <row id="0">
      <cell><![CDATA[1<div id='simple_id0' style='display:none;'><p id='simple_id1' style='display:none;'>1</p><p id='simle_id2' style='display:none;'>0</p><p id='simple_id3' style='display:none;'>3</p><p id="simple_id4">[{"ROWS":"1","Text1":"test"},{"ROWS":"1","Text2":"test2"},{"ROWS":"1","Text3":"test3"}]</p></div>]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[13]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[<a href='simple_href' class='href_track bold'>Name</a>]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[Text]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[Text]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[Text]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[Text]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[10-27-2015]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[16:01 PM]]></cell>
      <cell />
      <cell><![CDATA[17:46]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[<input type="button" class="checkin btn_univer" id="79" style='opacity:0.6;cursor:not-allowed;' disabled='disabled' value="Text" data-type="text">]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[<input type="button" class="checkout btn_univer" id="79"  value="Text" data-message="" data-type="text">]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[<a class='href_track bold' 
                            href='simple_href' 
                            target='_blank'>Text</a>]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[Status]]></cell>
   </row>
</rows>
```

Comment: **You should include the XML returned from the server.** You can use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or Developer Tools of IE/Chrome (press F12 to start and use Network tab) to create trace of HTTP traffic. It seems that you try to maintain **very old code** because it had jqGrid 3.3.1. I suppose that XML returned from the server could be really incorrect. I recommend you to migrate from usage of XML to the usage of JSON. Moreover the usage of still very old version 4.4.3 is also not the best choice. I recommend you to try [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) instead.

Comment: I already do this, i trace all of the XML and check them, and there is no error... It will be too complicated to change them from XML to JSON because there is more then 100 different webservices. Also i can't share any informations about XML (confidential information).

Comment: If you want that other people to help you then you should provide the corresponding information. You can easy reduce the XML code to two rows and to replace confidential information to some dummy data. Sorry, but your current question look like: "I have some code, which don't work and which I can't post you, can you help me to fix my code?" Do you believe that somebody can help you having such information?

Comment: I've put XML in post.

Comment: The code which you posted is do well-formed. You can use any inline validator like http://www.xmlvalidation.com/ to verify this. If you have problem in XML code, then you should find **the error in your original XML**, because the XML, which you posted is well formed. I still find very strange that you want to use such data for filling jqGrid. Are you sure? Moreover it's only the data, but you reported the problem in jqGrid. I see no JavaScript code which you use. What kind of solution you expect from other? One can't fix the code if you don't post it.

Comment: As i said, this is old application and all of this things are already implemented, so i need to save the application with minimal changes. I point to jqgrid because this error occur when i update jqgrid version(also all of the XML data is used only and only in jqgrid).

Comment: The changing from version 3.3.1 to 4.4.3 or any other version higher as 3.5 can't be small. You should either hold the old version and make small changes or probably rewrite your whole code. I'm afraid that you should solve the problem yourself.

Comment: As i said in the post, everything is working as expected except the console error, which only occurs in Firefox. I wanted to know why only in Firefox this error is present and what is the factor that do this. Thanks anyway for your time :)

Comment: You are welcome, but one can solve the problem only if one have enough information.